# In Robotium, Click on QuickAction icons

Tags: android-layout, robotium

Can any body tell that me how to click on the quick action icon [ buttons visible on screen with icon only- and without text labels ] in robotium. I need to automate some test cases, But i am not able automate that how to click on the quick action icon.

Thank You,
Manju

Answer (score 2):

[image]

click on first Quick icon - `solo.clickOnImageButton(0);` OR `solo.clickOnImage(0);`

click on second Quick icon - `solo.clickOnImageButton(1);` OR `solo.clickOnImage(1);`

Answer (score 0):

By "quick action icon" you mean a MenuItem in the ActionBar? You can click those in the overflow (and those shown withText) with solo.clickOnMenuItem("MenuItemTitle");

I am currently looking for a way to click those that have no visible title.